# Using Android Pie's *native* UVC webcam driver?

Tags: android, v4l2, uvc

Over the year's many people have made Android apps/libraries such as [UVCCamera](https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera) to view a UVC webcam video stream. However, the release notes for Android Pie seem to indicate that it now includes a native UVC driver:

> External camera support: Android 9 now supports external USB / UVC
>   cameras on certain devices. [[source]](https://www.android.com/versions/pie-9-0/)

As all of the unofficial libraries are very buggy, I'm very interested in trying out the new official driver. However, I've been unable to find any samples at all showing how to use it. Can anyone point me to a sample?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?, if yes can you please share more details?

Comment: @Deadpool I don't have a device that runs Pie, so I haven't really been able to work on it.